# how to properly pipe the output of a "bundle exec rake ..." command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, grep, pipe, rake

I have a rake take I run like this

```
be rake fix_pf_administrator_pct_assets
```

The rake task is part of a larger rails app.

There's a loop in the code, and a sleep 1,
so I get a very "real time" output of the script.

However,  if I do this

```
be rake fix_pf_administrator_pct_assets | grep mydebugprint
```

I have to wait till the whole script finishes before seeing the results.

How can I have real-time output of the script, while being able to grep
for interesting lines.

Comment: Try with the second option on the first answer in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20135059/bash-reading-stdout-stream-in-real-time

Comment: Basically, it runs the script outputing on a file called `output`, then moves the process to the background with `&`, then runs `tail -f` on that file to follow the changes and theeen it greps the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a systetm with GNU coreutils, you can force the output of the rake task to be line buffered: (assumes "be" is not a shell alias but a command)

```
stdbuf --output=L be rake fix_pf_administrator_pct_assets | grep mydebugprint
```

[`stdbuf(1)` man page](https://manpage.me/index.cgi?q=stdbuf&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+8.1.0&arch=default&format=html)

Comment: I'm on macOS at the moment